# What might cause linking errors that disappear on clean in fastOptJS?

Tags: scala, sbt, scala.js

Frequently `./sbt fastOptJS` throws a linking error at me, `Referring to non-existent method...`, that disappears if I run `./sbt clean` and then `./sbt fastOptJS` again.

I was wondering, what could be a possible cause for this? Is this likely a `build.sbt` misconfiguration issue? Common coding style pitfall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience this is most often caused by incremental compiler not recompiling enough of your sources on certain changes. One particular issue I have seen is method signature changes where only the inferred return type changed to cause this, like when changing:

```
def x(a: Int, b: Double) = a
```

to

```
def x(a: Int, b: Double) = b
```

If this is the case, using explicit return types often helps:

```
def x(a: Int, b: Double): Double = a
```

(In reality more complex code is required to trigger the issue.)

To me this happens both in Scala JS and Scala JVM. In Scala JVM it most often shows not during linking, but during execution, with the exception `NoSuchMethodError` thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Although I have accepted another answer, I'm adding this one in the hope that it is useful to someone else who comes searching.

https://github.com/sbt/zinc/issues/249

Zinc's support for Macros is not perfect, and on occasion the Macro's definition changes, but some files using the Macro did not, and so their compiled code does not change, either, resulting in missing functions on the last step.